# Allocating arrays for C++ + OpenGL + QT

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, malloc

I am with a issue in a QT + C++ +OpenGL project. The main problem is that I need to use a QText area to receive the number of cells in a array, but I'm not succeding. The fact is that, as the array is created within the moment my project starts to run I'd need to redifine it's size, and then use it... I've already tried using realloc(to reallocate more memory to my array) after using free(), but when I try to do it my results are either a unexpected shut of the execution or a lot of crazy plots...
What I really need to know is if I can pass the content in my TextArea to my Class CPonto(which contains the array) and then build the array, or if I should use a CPonto::reallocate like and then realloc or free()+calloc()/malloc the array to start the thing...
I know that's kind complex to understand, but I'm not understanding my issue too, I thought that the free+malloc/calloc would work...

Comment: when using C++ you shouldn't touch free or realloc, instead use the vector class

Comment: also show what you've tried till now, we'll help your way out

Answer (score 0):

Proper C++ code should never use C-style memory allocation (`malloc()`, `free()`, `realloc()` etc.). Instead, just store your resizable array as the standard C++ resizable array - a `std::vector`. Or, if you prefer Qt containers, `QVector` (but I personally prefer `std` containers any day).

Anyway, to address your `realloc()` issue itself: as the name suggests (and [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/realloc) specifies) `realloc()` **re**allocates memory. Which means it must receive valid memory in the first place. So you call `realloc()` *instead of* `free()`, not *after* it.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a pointer definition for your array!
lets say you have an array of Integers
like

```
`int myarray[10];`
```

you could use:

```
`int * myarray; //in the init
.....
have your data from textbox and put it in N 
....
myarray = new int(N);
....`
```

and use myarray as usuall like a normal array